# Compute the cumulative distribution function of the variable $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I've returned to the study of statistics after a long while and I'm trying to solve some problems. One of those is the next: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random independent variables with normal distribution $N(0,1)$, which has distribution function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)}$$

Compute the cumulative distribution function of the variable
$$R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$$

I'd appreciate some hints to solve these kind of problems. Thanks.

Comment: You may have some other random variable in mind. The sum $X+Y$ is normal mean $0$ variance $2$.  In particular, $X+Y$ is often negative, so $\sqrt{X+Y}$ is often not defined. From the name $R$ I would guess that you are interested in $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

Comment: First problem: $X+Y$ is not almost surely nonnegative...

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh, yeah, that's what I mean, I'm going to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. We want to find the cumulative distribution function $F_R(w)$ of $R$. This is $\Pr(R\le w)$. Note that $\Pr(R\le w)=0$ if $w\lt 0$, so from now on we assume $w\ge 0$.  We have 
$$\Pr(R\le w)=\iint_D \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dx\,dy,$$
where $D$ is the disk with centre the origin and radius $w$.
To evaluate the integral, go to polar coordinates. Our integral is equal to
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^w \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}r\,dr\right)\,d\theta.$$
The integration is straightforward (let $u=r^2/2$). We get $1-e^{-w^2/2}$.